# Extracting First_name & Last_name from email oracle using Reg_exp

Tags: sql, oracle

How to extract First_name & last_name from email using oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR,

Email: `susan.ryan@email.com`

Expected output:

| First_name | Last_name |
| --- | --- |
| susan | ryan |

```
select
  substr('susan.ryan@email.com',1,(INSTR('susan.ryan@email.com','.')-1)) first_name,
  substr('susan.ryan@email.com',(INSTR('susan.ryan@email.com','.')+1),(INSTR('susan.ryan@email.com','@'))) last_name
from dual;
```

But i'm getting result as

| first_name | Last_name |
| --- | --- |
| susan | ryan@email. |

Comment: On a side note: If you want to create sample data on-the-fly, you can use a `WITH` clause, so you don't have to repeat the same string again and again and can easily add more rows to your test: `with mytable as (select 'susan.ryan@email.com' as email from dual) select substr(email, 1, instr(email, '.') - 1) as first_name, substr(email, instr(email, '.') + 1, instr(email, '@')) as last_name from mytable;`.

Comment: I've remove the PL/SQL tag from your request. PL/SQL is Oracle's programming language built into the database. Your question is about SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
substr(email, instr(email, '.') + 1, instr(email, '@')) as last_name
```

But the second parameter is not the end position, but the requested length, so you must subtract the position of the dot:

```
substr(email, instr(email, '.') + 1, instr(email, '@') - instr(email, '.') - 1) as last_name
```

That's easier with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` by the way:

```
regexp_substr(email, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 1) as first_name,
regexp_substr(email, '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 2) as last_name
```

We are looking for substrings that only consist of letters in the e-mail here. For first_name we are taking the first such string, for last_name the second one. This relies of course on all e-mails in your table equally consisting of firstname.lastname@domain.

Here is the docs on `REGEXP_SUBSTR`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099

Comment: And here is a query to find malformed e-mails in your table: `select * from mytable where not regexp_like(email, '^[[:alpha:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]+@[[:alpha:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]+$');`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of how to do this. First remove the domain using `SUBSTR` (column "domain") or `REGEXP` (column "domain_regexp"), then split the portion before the domain (column "no_domain") using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
WITH samples AS
(
  SELECT '-susan.ryan@email.com' as str FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'roger@email.com' as str FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
str as email,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'@.+$') AS domain_regexp,
SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str,'@')) as domain,
SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str,'@') - 1) as no_domain,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str,'@') - 1),'[^.]+',1,1) AS first_name,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str,'@') - 1),'[^.]+',1,2) AS last_name
from samples;

EMAIL                 DOMAIN_REGEXP         DOMAIN                NO_DOMAIN             FIRST_NAME            LAST_NAME            
--------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
-susan.ryan@email.com @email.com            @email.com            -susan.ryan           -susan                ryan                 
roger@email.com       @email.com            @email.com            roger                 roger
```

Comment: whenever we have email as  'susan.ryan.john@email.com' we are getting values as 
first_name :-Susan
Last_name :-ryan.

how to overcome this and get values as
first_name :-Susan
Last_name :-ryan.john

Comment: Please update your question with this additional info. What if the first name contains a "." ? This changes the rules entirely. You now are asking "give me everything before first "." " - that is first name, then give me everything after first "." until the "@" - that is last name. This should be done with SUBSTR and INSTR as explained by @Thorsten